# Region of interest in fingerprint image

Tags: opencv, fingerprint

I am working on a fingerprint recognition project with OpenCV. Currently I need to extract the inner region in fingerprint (ellipse in image), but I am not sure how to do it.

[image]

Any suggestion is appreciated.

**EDIT**:

I need to check if a fingerprint from sensor device and another from identification card match or not. The fingerprint in sensor is as follow (left) meanwhile in identification card is as right fingerprint. In order to validate them, it is required to segment this fingerprint (outside the ellipse doesn't provide useful information but indeed adds "noise" for this purpose).

[image]

Thank you.

Comment: create a mask (white inside the ellipse and black outside) you can do this with `ellipse` function and `-1` in the thickness. Then copy the image using the mask (bitwise_and for python or copyTo for c++ should do it)... you will always have a squared image, but you will have black (or the color you want) outside the ellipse

Comment: @api55. Thank you for your answer.
However my doubt is because the fingerprint doesn't have same position in every image, then the ellipse can not be a fixed mask. How to define where the ellipse region is...

Comment: well to define a ellipse you need 5 points. The center and the extreme points of each axis... I do not know what you consider that is the inner region of the fingerprint. The example image could have a bigger ellipse, maybe even rotated to cover more inner region.

Comment: @api55, I edited my question to add some extra information...

Answer (score 1):

@API55's comment is correct, for clarity:

> create a mask (white inside the ellipse and black outside) you can do this with ellipse function and -1 in the thickness. Then copy the image using the mask (bitwise_and for python or copyTo for c++ should do it)... you will always have a squared image, but you will have black (or the color you want) outside the ellipse

These steps are pretty much spot on,

1. Create your circular mask in the correct place in the image
2. Copy the image using that mask
3. Your new image contains the mask data, and black data everywhere else.

below is an example of how to implement this in code:

( I lovingly borrowed from [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/101116/pixel-datas-in-a-circular-region/))

```
Mat img = imread("small1.png", 0); // load gray
Rect region(10,10,40,40); // example roi
Mat roi(img, region);  // part of img
Mat mask(Size(40,40), CV_8U, Scalar(0)); // all black
circle(mask, Point(20,20), 20, Scalar(255), -1, LINE_AA); // filled circle
Mat circRoi;
bitwise_and(roi, roi, circRoi, mask); // retain only pixels inside the circle
//
// now you can do your intensity calculation on circRoi
//
imshow("circle masked", mask);
imshow("masked roi", circRoi);
waitKey();
```

**Useful Links**

- [Why ROIs don't have to be circular but Mats do](http://answers.opencv.org/question/53781/roi-always-a-rectangle/)
- [Older code example, useful for learning the theory but I wouldnt recommend implementing using IPLimage](http://www.voidcn.com/article/p-srbrzhzo-ua.html)
- [Creating a custom ROI of any shape or size](http://www.pieter-jan.com/node/5)

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
However my doubt is because the fingerprint doesn't have same position in every image, then the ellipse can not be a fixed mask. How to define where the ellipse region is...

Comment: You'll have to write some image processing to detect the correct location but that's quite a different question to the one you had originally posted and this answer refers to

Answer (score 0):

```
int main() {

    string path = "Resources/1/*";

    vector<String> fn;
    vector<Mat> data;
    glob(path, fn, true);
    int cntr = 0;
    Mat inputImage, binaryimage;

    for (size_t k = 0; k < fn.size(); ++k){

        inputImage = imread(fn[k]);
        cout << fn[k] << endl;

        Mat gray;
        cvtColor(inputImage,gray, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);

        Mat normalizedImage;
        cv::normalize(gray, normalizedImage, 15, 255, NORM_MINMAX);
        imshow("inpnorm", normalizedImage);

        Mat imgdil, imgerode;
        Mat kernel = getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(3, 3));
        dilate(normalizedImage, imgdil, kernel);
        //erode(imgdil, imgerode, kernel);

        Mat normalizImg;
        cv::normalize(imgdil, normalizImg, 25, 255, NORM_MINMAX);
        cv::normalize(normalizImg, normalizImg, 25, 255, NORM_MINMAX);

        Mat thre;
        adaptiveThreshold(normalizImg, thre, 255, ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, THRESH_BINARY_INV, 25, 1.9);

        cv::normalize(thre, normalizImg, 15, 255, NORM_MINMAX);
        cv::normalize(normalizImg, normalizImg, 15, 255, NORM_MINMAX);
        cv::normalize(normalizImg, thre, 17, 255, NORM_MINMAX); 

        string savingName = "fingerprints00/" + to_string(++cntr) + ".jpg";
        imwrite(savingName, thre);

        imshow("original image", inputImage);
        //imshow("norm", normalizImg);
        imshow("thresh", thre);
        moveWindow("original image",0,0);
        moveWindow("thresh",600,0);
        waitKey(0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

opencv c++ for fingerprint extraction from finger image,change the path,
thank me later